# NullPointerException while performing multiple client concurrent updates in Apache Ignite

Tags: jmeter, ignite, gridgain

I am getting following error while performing concurrent updates using multiple clients. Multiple clients threads are created in Apache Jmeter.

> 2016/11/03 15:00:57 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Error while processing sampler 'Java Request' : java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at ignite_client_jmeter.new_order(ignite_client_jmeter.java:857)
>           at ignite_client_jmeter.runTest(ignite_client_jmeter.java:1659)
>           at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler.sample(JavaSampler.java:196)
>           at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:465)
>           at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:410)
>           at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:241)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Following is the part where error occurs at line 857 while accessing data that is retrieved using cache get() operation. Code works fine with single client. But for more than 1 client some times it throws above mentioned NullPointerException error.

**Update Query**

```
      //UPDATE district SET d_next_o_id = ? + 1 WHERE d_id = ? AND d_w_id = ?

      districtKey dkey = new districtKey(district_num, warehouse_num);
      System.out.println("Thread_ id = "+thread_num+", district_num = "+district_num+", warehouse_num = "+warehouse_num);

      IgniteTransactions transactions = ignite.transactions();
      try (Transaction tx = ignite.transactions().txStart(TransactionConcurrency.PESSIMISTIC,
                TransactionIsolation.SERIALIZABLE)) {
          district dist = (district) cache_district.get(dkey);

          assert dist != null;

          if(dist == null)
              System.out.println("......Thread_ id = "+thread_num+", district_num = "+district_num+", warehouse_num = "+warehouse_num);


          dist.d_next_o_id = d_next_o_id + 1;  //Line number 857
          d_next_o_id = d_next_o_id + 1;

          cache_district.put(dkey, dist);
          tx.commit();
      }
      catch (CacheException e) {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof TransactionTimeoutException &&
                e.getCause().getCause() instanceof TransactionDeadlockException)    

                System.out.println(e.getCause().getCause().getMessage());
        }         

      Integer o_id; 
      o_id = d_next_o_id;
```

Comment: So which line is it (code snippet does not show numbers)? What is null?

Comment: Sorry, line number is irrelevent here but this is line at which the error occurs `dist.d_next_o_id = d_next_o_id + 1;  //Line number 857`. As I was getting nullpointerexception error I was just trying to print out thread number at which I am getting error using condition `if(dist == null)`(when this error occurs I am getting null value in **dist**)

Comment: This only means that the value for this key does not exist in cache. How do you make sure that it's there? Do you have a full test that I can run?

Comment: Side note: unless you started JMeter with `-ea` command-line parameter, assert is not going to do anything. I would suggest `if(dist == null) throw new AssertionError();` - this is equivalent of your code, but it will always run

Comment: Valentin, sorry I cant provide code, but this is the part were error occurs. This part works fine when single thread is working, but fails sometimes when when there is more than 1 thread. This Update query part is only client side code. Cache entries are put in on server side code(So, in both cases (1 thread and more than 1 thread)) all entries are present in cache.